# Errors launching Redmine, Debian/Apache2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Upon launching a Redmine with the command `ruby script/server -e production`, the following errors are raised:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- initializer (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /var/www/redmine/config/boot.rb:60:in `load_initializer'
    from /var/www/redmine/config/boot.rb:43:in `run'
    from /var/www/redmine/config/boot.rb:16:in `boot!'
    from /var/www/redmine/config/boot.rb:119
    from script/server:2:in `require'
    from script/server:2
```

I have thoroughly searched for the issue I have having but to no avail.  What is the cause of this error?

Thanks in advance, Daniel

Comment: Have you installed all gems required by Redmine?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issues with your Rails gem.

The question can be found on the Redmine wiki [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/FAQ#When-I-start-the-application-I-get-this-error-in-gem_original_require-no-such-file-to-load-initializer-LoadError).

Most likely you haven't installed a number of the gems required to launch/run the server.

Assuming you have [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) installed, run `bundle install` from the redmine root directory.